# the meaning: 'termwinkey' CTRL-\ send a CTRL-\ to the job in the terminal

Tags: key-bindings

In the manual:

```
'termwinkey' CTRL-\    send a CTRL-\ to the job in the terminal
```

It don't explain what `CTRL-\` mean for the job in the terminal,it means stop the job or something else?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226333

Comment: What CTRL-\ means, depends on the job that is running. So basically, this will send Ctrl-\ to the running job.